# Best way of Integrating Rollbar with Spring Boot / jHipster?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, rollbar

I'm trying to integrate https://rollbar.com/ into a Jhipster Application.

In their [documentation](https://github.com/RollbarExample/Rollbar-Java-Example/blob/master/src/main/java/com/in28minutes/controller/GlobalExceptionHandlerController.java), they suggest to create a class like the following:

```
@ControllerAdvice
@EnableWebMvc
public class GlobalExceptionHandlerController {

    public static final String DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW = "error";

    @ExceptionHandler(value = Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView defaultErrorHandler(HttpServletRequest req, Exception e) throws Exception {

        final Rollbar rollbar = new Rollbar(withAccessToken("8e194f5f31db4ff1b4e3e0951a40c936")
                .environment("production").handleUncaughtErrors(true).build());
        rollbar.error(e);
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.addObject("exception", e);
        mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL());
        mav.setViewName(DEFAULT_ERROR_VIEW);
        return mav;
    }
```

However, jHipster already has a class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`: `public class ExceptionTranslator implements ProblemHandling`, and if I add the above method, the rollbar integration works, but then I get failed tests for

```
ExceptionTranslatorIntTest.testExceptionWithResponseStatus:126 Status expected:<400> but was:<200>
  ExceptionTranslatorIntTest.testInternalServerError:135 Status expected:<500> but was:<200>
```

Since the new method prevents entering the `ExceptionTranslator.process(@Nullable ResponseEntity<Problem> entity)` method.

I'm not sure what is a good approach to achieve both functionalities?

Thank You!

Comment: I think that Rollbar it's not thought out for Spring Boot yet, which is what jhipster is built in. I ended up switching to bugsnag. I'm leaving this open since it might help someone but changing its original title to add spring boot, the bugsnug spring boot integration is very straight forward, just create a @Configuration class.